# Convert String containing bytes to Normal String in java?

Tags: java

I am having String containing bytes and i want to convert it to normal String but getting exception

```
String a = "abhishek";
System.out.println(a.getBytes());
getting bytes from a 
String b ="[B@4fe5e2c3";
byte[] btDataFile = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(a);
String c = new String(btDataFile);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: How are the bytes encoded? What is in `a` doesn't seem [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Definitely not base64. Looks like the representation of a memory address.

Comment: As you have used Base64 encoding use the same for decoding.

Comment: No Simple String.getBytes()

Answer (score 1):

The method `getBytes()` returns an *array* of `byte`.

The default implementation of `toString()` for arrays prints out an internal type signature and hashCode for the array, which in your case is the value `[B@4fe5e2c3`.

If you wanted to output the actual values you should use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Actually the bytes are coming as a String  from webservice. I need to convert those bytes present in the String to normal string.

Comment: @abhishekkhune "The bytes are coming as a String from webservice"... I think you'll need to tell us what this string looks like.  I'm sure it doesn't look like `"[B@4fe5e2c3"`.